# Parsing error stack

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am catching an error through a code like this:

```
...
catch(error){
  ... error.stack ...
}
...
```

This `error.stack` is a string as far as I know. Is there a jQuery function that parses this into an array of lines of file name, line, function? Or, is there an alternative to `stack` that directly gives an array?

Answer (score 2):

Its not jquery specific but take a look at [stacktrace.js](http://stacktracejs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not an Expert.But trying to answer

```
var stack=error.stack;
for(i=0;i<stack.Length;i++){
var arrstack +=stack.split(" ");
}
```